# How to reduce height of  scrollviewer in tabcontrol?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, xaml, layout

I have a customUserControl which is hosted in a TabItem of TabControl in silverlight application. This TabControl is part of a big UI container with splitters.

My requirement is to resize customUserControl when I resize the TabControl using splitters in UI. But usercontrol should not go below its minimum height of 500px; if TabControl goes below this height, a scroll should appear.

I have done following for this

```
<WindowsControls:TabItem Header="Live Update"
                                 x:Name="tabLiveUpdate"
                                 Margin="3,0,0,0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0"
                              Padding="1" 
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              Width="Auto">
                        <MyControls:customUserControl 
                                       DataContext="{Binding Path=LiveUpdateVm}"
                                       MinHeight="500"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </WindowsControls:TabItem>
```

It shows a scrollbar when application loads up as start-up width of TabControl is less than 500px.
As I increase the size of TabControl using splitters to more than 500px(e.g. upto 700px) the usercontrol increases it size too. And scroll disappear

Up to this this is fine behavior as I expect.

**The problem is** when I downsize the TabControl back to some where between current(700) and minimum(500), say 600px, it does not downsize the usercontrol. Rather It shows a scroll bar now even with a height of 600. Expected behavior is to show scrollbar only if size reaches below 500

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Either limit the size of the `Stackpanel`, or replace it with a `Grid`.

```
<WindowsControls:TabItem Header="Live Update"
                                 x:Name="tabLiveUpdate"
                                 Margin="3,0,0,0">
            <Grid horizontalalignment="stretch" verticalalignment="stretch">

                <ScrollViewer BorderThickness="0"
                              Padding="1" 
                              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                              horizontalalignment="stretch" verticalalignment="stretch">

                        <MyControls:customUserControl 
                                       DataContext="{Binding Path=LiveUpdateVm}"
                                       MinHeight="500"
                                       horizontalalignment="stretch" verticalalignment="stretch"/>
                    </ScrollViewer>
            </Grid>
        </WindowsControls:TabItem>
```

Comment: As you have seen in question I tried with grid but it does not work.